# What does "Directory.Delete( "path", false )" do?

Tags: .net

According to the doucmentation for "Directory.Delete( "path", true )", it remove directories, subdirectories, and files in the path.

What does Directory.Delete( "path", false ) do? According to the doucmentation it does "otherwise".

I mean how can you delete a directory without removing the directory, subdirectories, and files?

Answer (score 8):

Bill James is correct. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx), if the *recursive* parameter is false and the directory is not empty, IOException will be thrown.

Comment: You are right, that was burried in the exception explanations.

Comment: Fine, DO the research then, TAKE the upticks :)  Where's that guy griping about fastest gun in the West, again?

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick guess, since I don't do .Net, but I'd say it will only remove empty directories.

Comment: Ya, I know, but it really was just an educated guess.  jleedev actually looked it up, which I can admit was more work than I was willing to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Second argument tells whether you want a recursive delete. If it's false, the method will throw an IOException if the directory is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the intent of the code is to delete directories only if they're empty.  Setting the second parameter to `false` enforces that policy/intent.